# How is the calculation working for this jquery using Datatables row offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My JavaScript code is:

```
var selectedRow = $('#tblCompany tbody tr').eq(index);
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop(selectedRow.prop('offsetTop') - $('.dataTables_scrollBody').height() / 2)

$('.dataTables_scrollBody').height()       // is set to 300 px
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').height() / 2)  // 300 / 2 = 150
```

When I do that:

- for first Row 0, `selectedRow.prop('offsetTop')` is reporting: 0
- for row 16: `selectedRow.prop('offsetTop')` is reporting: 509

I want to understand how this 509 is calculated, is it from the top of the asp.net form? or from the top of the `tblCompany` table?

Here is the HTML Page:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body style="font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 12px;">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <h3>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltopmsg" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp; Data is being loaded.. Please wait several seconds" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
    </h3>

    <table id="tblJquery" align="center" runat="server" width="80%">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="divtop" style="width: 80%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">

            <table id="tblCompany" border="0" class="cell-border compact stripe" style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: medium">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th id="thcompany">CompanyRecordID</th>
                  <th>PermitNumberSuffix</th>
                  <th>CompanyName</th>
                  <th>City</th>
                  <th>Issue&nbsp;Date</th>
                  <th>Action</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody></tbody>

              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>CompanyRecordID</th>
                  <th>PermitNumberSuffix</th>
                  <th>CompanyName</th>
                  <th>City</th>
                  <th>Issue&nbsp;Date</th>
                  <th>Action</th>

                </tr>

              </tfoot>
            </table>


          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: the HTML code consists of :  <body style="font-family: Century Gothic; font-size: 12px;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server"> and   <table id="tblCompany"  with <thead> </thead> and <tbody></tbody>